# How to determine feature relevance using ‘Weights’ method?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, feature-selection, weights

The following photo displays the ‘Weights’ method for determining feature relevance in a neural network model.

Source: http://sovan.lek.free.fr/publi/160-3%20Gevrey.pdf

NB: For anyone confused I believe ‘nh’ must denote the no. of hidden neurons and ‘ni’ denote the no. of input neurons.

[image]

[image]

What isn’t clear to me is how to calculate $Q_{ih}$ if there is more than one hidden layer. Do you just use the weights into the first hidden layer and disregard the rest?

Comment: The paper specifically assumes a single hidden layer.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy the thing is I read another paper that said it adopts the weights method from this paper (no other details given). In the other paper 2 hidden layers were used.